# How to rename files within subfolder to the parent directory and retain file extension - Powershell

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I'm having issues running a loop which allows files within subfolders to be name from its parent directory. My current file structure is as follows:

```
C:\test data
      Folder 1 [4k]
          12345676.txt
          35234443.mp4
          23432234.avi
      Folder 2 [4k]
          56859522.txt
          35234443.mp4
          23432234.avi
```

The desired end-result.

```
C:\test data
      Folder 1
         Folder 1.txt
         Folder 1.mp4
         Folder 1.avi
      Folder 2
         Folder 2.txt
         Folder 2.mp4
         Folder 2.avi
```

Here is my code which I'm trying to modify

```
$path = "C:\test data" 

Get-ChildItem $path -Directory | Foreach-Object { 

$file = $_.Fullname
$file = $file -replace ('4K','')
$file = $file -replace ('\s+\[]','')

Write-Output $file

rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName $file

Get-ChildItem $path
} 

### Rename files in Subfolders 
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -File | Foreach-Object { 
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName 
    ($_.Directory.name) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

The script changes the name of the file but does not retain the extension.

```
C:\test data
      Folder 1
          Folder 1 (file)
          Folder 1 (file)
          Folder 1 (file)
      Folder 2
          Folder 2 (file)
          Folder 2 (file)
          Folder 2 (file)
```

Any information would be of great help since I'm still learning how to code in Powershell.

Answer (score 3):

The file extension can be accessed via the aptly named [`Extension` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.extension?view=net-6.0):

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -File | Foreach-Object { 
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName ($_.Directory.Name + $_.Extension) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

Comment: what about the removal of `[4k]` in the folder name?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala OP already solved that

Comment: Ahh, thought they wanted to incorporate it into the script lol just wanted to see your take on it. Thx!

Comment: My personal preference would be `$name.Replace('[4K]','').Trim()` :)